# Mediawiki Extension:RSS

Tags: rss, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-extensions

The MediaWiki Extension:RSS (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RSS) uses the plainlinks class to present the RSS feed link. I have tried all manner of searching, including trying to edit the MediaWiki:Rss-feed template to force the link to presented in non-bolded format.

Has anyone used this extension and can tell me how to change the fonts in the RSS link?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to provide a screen shot showing exactly what you mean, especially as RSS is just an XML wrapper. Is the problem with the web page where the link to the RSS feed is given, with the RSS feed itself (in which case check a couple or readers), or what? Also, sometimes you get more love posting on the extension:talk pages (e.g. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:RSS). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you should be able to remove the boldface formatting from the RSS item titles by editing the page `MediaWiki:Rss-item` (*not* `MediaWiki:Rss-feed`) on your wiki.

What you need to do is two things:

1. remove the string `'''` (MediaWiki markup for bold text) from either side of the title, and
2. remove the `;` (MediaWiki markup for a list definition, which is also bolded by the default style sheet) from the beginning of the line.

That is, change the default content of the page:

```
; '''<span class='plainlinks'>[{{{link}}} {{{title}}}]</span>'''
: {{{description}}}
: {{{author}}} {{{date}}}<!-- don't use newline here -->
```

to this:

```
<span class='plainlinks'>[{{{link}}} {{{title}}}]</span>
: {{{description}}}
: {{{author}}} {{{date}}}<!-- don't use newline here -->
```

Comment: Thanks. That got it. It's actually Rss-feed that works for that fix. Thanks so much for your time!